# Threshold image on python also segment

Tags: python, image

```
from PIL import Image
import  ImageOps
im= Image.open("new.jpeg")
imout=im.PIL.ImageOps.solarize(image, threshold=40)
imout.show()
```

I want to threshold an image to 40% with the above code but is is showing the error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meraj\Desktop\script captcha\captchat.py", line 4, in <module>
    imout=im.PIL.ImageOps.solarize(image, threshold=128)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pillow-2.3.2-py2.7-win32.egg\PIL\Image.py", line 528, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: PIL
```

I will also segment the hole image to 20. How will i do that? Can you give me full code ?
i am new to python So I am unable to find how to do that? I am finding from one week. Can you give me proper link to tutorial with video ?

Comment: Obviously, the `im` object has no attribute `PIL`. Just use `PIL.ImageOps.solarize`.

Comment: _"Can you give me full code?"_ No, SO is a Q&A site, not a code writing service. _"Can you give me proper link to tutorial with video?"_ Sorry, recommendation requests for tutorials are off-topic as well.

Comment: PIL.ImageOps.solarize is also not working :-File "C:\Users\Meraj\Desktop\script captcha\captchat.py", line 4, in <module>
    imout=PIL.ImageOps.solarize(im, threshold=128)
NameError: name 'PIL' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import cv2

import Image


im_gray = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)

(thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
thresh = 90
im_bw = cv2.threshold(im_gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
cv2.imwrite('bw_image.png', im_bw)
```

this is the solution i found for shareholding images. Changing the value of thresh variable will change the threshold percentage